# Database of Gematria, Notarikon, and Temurah Findings

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, science, gematria-numerology

I have been aware of [Gematria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria), but now just learned of [Notarikon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notarikon) and [Temurah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temurah_(Kabbalah)).

There is a cool twitter feed by the [TilingBot](https://twitter.com/TilingBot) on hyperbolic tessellations. It is essentially a database of all the types of hyperbolic tessellations found. In a similar way, I am wondering if there is a database of findings in Gematria, Notarikon, and Temurah, in regards to what patterns have been found, basically a big list of patterns. Does anything like this exist?

For example, certain sentences translated according to each Gematria method, (or every sentence translated with every method several ways). And how much analysis has been done, especially from a scientific standpoint on it, as Wikipedia says several scholars believe there is a significance to it.

Comment: Hi @Lance I would recommend you explore the writings of the Ba'al HaTurim on the Torah who features the use of Gematriah regularly.

Comment: There has also been a lot written about 'Torah Codes' namely the equal spacing of letters in the Torah to spell out messages etc. Gematriahs do feature there as well. Here's a good intro to the idea that you might find interesting - https://www.aish.com/atr/Torah_Codes_Explained.html